# Leveraging FusionAuth login / verify screens

Tags: fusionauth

We have two administrative SPAs that can make easy use of the FusionAuth templated login / verify screens. This is useful as the screens automatically reflect our social logins as those are configured,

The third SPA is carefully designed and places the login fields on a dynamic splash page. I'm considering an attempt to html embed the FusionAuth login panel on our splash page but would need to strip away the nav bar and background container. I think this would be a global change to the FusionAuth UI web layout, forcing the use of embeds in all our apps.

We have FusionAuth running on a subdomain so an embed might not cause much CORS difficulty. Are there any other reasons that embedding the login panel directly from the FusionAuth server into our pages might not be a workable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the FusionAuth login UI without impacting the administration UI. If you go to `Settings` -> `System` -> `UI`, you will see that the Login UI templates can all be modified.

If you have different login UI elements for different Applications, you can use the variable `client_id` in the templates to control the layout. This is the OAuth `client_id` that for the FusionAuth Application. These templates are FreeMarker, so a conditional statement might look like this:

```
[#if client_id == 'ee31103f-2fc1-4bb5-ba95-ac543693503e']
  Embeddable HTML/CSS goes here
[#else]
  Standard HTML/CSS goes here
[/#if]
```

That being said, the OAuth login UI of FusionAuth might not be easily embeddable in your third SPA depending on if you are using an iframe or AJAX. It is still probably a better idea to skin the login UI to match your UI instead and leverage the OAuth login workflow if possible.

The other solution is to use your own login page and then call the FusionAuth APIs to authenticate the user.

We have been exploring adding an embeddable login system. If you want to open a feature request for this, you can add it on our Github Issue tracker here: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues